# Need assistance with Excel, VBA and userforms, specifically over writing existing data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently developing a data input system at my place of work, utilising userforms for ease of input and have got a bit stuck on some of the coding. I want it to check if the reference number inserted into the form is in the data already saved, and if not add the data as a new row. I've managed this aspect but am stuck on the next part - over writing the existing data if the reference number is present. My code so far is

```
Sub savebutton_click ()

Dim emptyrow As Long
Dim r as Excel.Range

Set r = sheets("data").range("a:a").find(what:=Auditref.Text.LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:= True)

If r Is Nothing then
    emptyrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(range("a:a")) + 1
    Cells(emptyrow, 1).value = auditref.value
    Cells(emptyrow, 2).value = datereview. Value
Else
    k = Auditref.Value
    Cells(kRow, 2).value = datereview.value
End if

End sub
```

It is raising an error at the cells(kRow, 2) point and I am lost as to how to sort this.

Any ideas?

Comment: `krow` isn't defined. Shouldn't it be `r.row` anyway ? You should also use sheet references throughout.

Comment: For some reason, I thought I'd have to define something as the audit ref again. Does defining k as the audit ref and then combining it with row not search for the row that reference number is in (that was my logic which could very well be wrong). I'll make the change as suggested and see if it works

Comment: You don't have a problem with the space in `Worsheet Function`?

Comment: That'd be a typo, it's not in the code I'm running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
Dim sht as worksheet, r as range

set sht = sheets("data")
Set r = sht.range("a:a").find(what:=Auditref.Text, _
                              LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:= True)

If r Is Nothing then set r = sht.cells(sht.rows.count, 1).end(xlup).offset(1, 0)
with r.entirerow
    .cells(1).value = auditref.value
    .Cells(2).value = datereview.value
end with
```

Are you sure you want `xlPart` in the `Find()` there? Seems like you'd want an exact match...